# convert uploaded file stream into string

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, stream

I want to use UploadedTextFile.FileContent to read file's content and save it as string . but it returns a set of encoding-like characters . this is the code :

```
string content = (new streamReader(UploadedTextFile.FileContent,true)).ReadToEnd();
```

but the result is something like this

```
 yua%^#@568sda_sdf89 ....
```

file content is not english .

Comment: Isn't the Stream class abstract in C#?

Comment: sorry , It's streamReader . question is updated

Comment: Is the uploaded file a text file?

Comment: You're attempting to detect the encoding from the beginning of the file - what encoding *should* the file be? Is it plaintext? If so, just remove the second parameter. If you know its always going to be a certain encoding, you can specify the encoding in the constructor instead.

Comment: @Blachshma : it's a .doc file

Comment: @ngmiceli : it's a .doc file without any formatting .

Comment: Microsoft Word documents have *tons* of formatting content in there as well. Try opening a .doc file in Notepad. What you see there is what you're going to get, regardless of encoding.

Comment: @ ngmiceli : thank you , it  was exactly what the convert returns . so the problem is the file itself

Comment: No problem! Converting to an answer for posterity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft Word documents have tons of formatting content in there as well. Try opening a .doc file in Notepad. What you see there is what you're going to get, regardless of encoding.

If you still want to try and extract the content from the document, there are tools in C# to help you out. I recommend reading the answer in [this link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/da-DK/oxmlsdk/thread/cb26e9a4-b150-44cd-8392-3d79ebe09745)